# How to force Android XML vector graphics to scale to fill an image button?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-vectordrawable

I've made my own version of an action bar across the bottom of the screen for my app, and have encountered a puzzling issue with icons placed in the buttons of that action bar. The layout is really simple.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/navbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:foregroundTint="@color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_list_48"
            android:contentDescription="Map Button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_popup_reminder"
            android:contentDescription="Notifications Button" />
```

The issue I'm encountering is when using a "system" icon like in the "Notifications Button" above, that icon properly scales to fill the ImageButton. But when using an icon that was created from a system icon like the "Map Button" above, the icon does NOT scale to fill the ImageButton like it should. Is there a way to make it do so?

Comment: Have you tried using `android:scaleType="fitxy"` it should work well if `@drawable/ic_list_48` is squarish.

Comment: I tried that on the ImageButton but it did nothing.

Comment: @drawable/ic_list_48 use this as background

Answer (score 0):

try

```
android:scaleType="fitxy"
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Actually this is necessary IN ADDITION TO the above answer from @Cheticamp.

Answer (score 0):

Your icons are not scaling up to fit the *ImageButtons* but, rather, the *ImageButtons* are scaling to fit the icons which each have an intrinsic width because you specify 'wrap_content'. You can see that here:

[image]

The left button has the standard vector drawable launch icon (width/height=108dp) and the icon on the right is the system defined PNG with a size that varies by platform.

You don't specify how you want the layout to look, but I suggest the following:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/navbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
        android:contentDescription="Map Button"
        android:foregroundTint="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
        android:contentDescription="Notifications Button"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_popup_reminder" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here weights are used to expand the size of the icons. This results in the following:

[image]

Comment: The solution that worked for me was a combination of the answer below from @Aashutosh and parts of this answer.

Specifically from this answer, setting WIDTH to zero AND setting layout_weight to 1 are what made the difference. I'm not sure why this works instead of WRAP_CONTENT though.

Comment: Also, the way I was doing it, the layout view in Android Studio showed the button to be the same size at all times. Only the Drawable (icon) would change size. You can see this because the two images in the Split View show outlines on one panel and content on the other.

Although note that I used "fitCenter" instead of "fitXY" for a cleaner look.